# Graph theory problem, diameter and average pairs distance

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Claim : There exists a positive natural number c so that for all connected graphs G, it
is the case that: (diam(G) / apd(G)) <= c.

This claim is false and we can show that for any c > 0, we can still construct a graph G such that (diam(G) / apd(G)) > c.

But what if,

Claim: There exists a constant c so that for any connected graph G, it
is the case that: (diam(G) / apd(G)) <= c.

Could someone proof or give an counterexample?

Comment: What's the difference between "for all connected graphs G" and "for any connected graph G"?

Comment: If you change *"any"* to *"a"*, then the second claim is clearly true. As is, I see no difference between the two claims.

Comment: I think the only different is constant and positive natural number. I didn't type the questions correctly.

Comment: It is confusing that in the first claim you write "for all", and in the second "for any". What is the significance of that difference in wording?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no difference between the wording "for **all** connected graphs" and "for **any** connected graph".

As you clarified in comments, the difference between the two claims concerns the domain of *c*. In the first claim it must be a *positive natural*, in the second claim nothing more is said about *c*. It is a constant. Note that also for the first claim it is a constant, as that follows from *"There exists...so that for all"*. So the only difference is that in the second case, *c* does not necessarily need to be a positive natural. It could for instance be a positive rational number or a negative integer.

This means that in the second claim, *c* has a larger domain, but one that includes the positive naturals. So if you have a counter example disproving the first claim, where *c* is a positive natural, this counter example will also serve as counter example for disproving the second claim, since that *c* is a "constant" and just happens to be a positive natural constant.